# how to sort parent to child as well as numeric index in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have one collection called **location**. this location is n level tree view. when data display in frontend it must be sort according to its **preferredIndex**.

> Collection

```
    const locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: { type: String },
          image: { type: String },
          imageManipulation: { type: String },
          locationColor: [{ range: { type: String }, color: { type: String } }],
          area: {},
          settings: {},
          status: { type: String, enum: [0, 1], default: 1 },
          isChild: { type: String, enum: [0, 1] },
          parentPosition: { type: String },
          svgSetting:{},
          preferredIndex: { type: Number }
}, { collection: 'location' });
```

> Current Query

```
locationModel.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    $and: [{
                            "status": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "businessId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decode._id)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$graphLookup": {
                    "from": "location",
                    "startWith": "$parentId",
                    "connectFromField": "parentId",
                    "connectToField": "_id",
                    "as": "parent"
                }
            },

            {
                "$project": {
                    "name": {
                        "$concat": [{
                                "$reduce": {
                                    "input": "$parent",
                                    "initialValue": "",
                                    "in": {
                                        "$concat": ["$$value", "$$this.name", ","]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "$name"
                        ]
                    },
                    // "preferredIndex": 1
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    // "name":1,
                    "preferredIndex": 1
                }
            },
        ])
```

> Current Query Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d41878b7396b445745438fc"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "ground floor,bad room"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187c07396b445745438fd"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "ground floor,bad room,bad"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187d57396b445745438fe"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "top floor"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4188067396b445745438ff"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "top floor,left top floor"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187657396b445745438fb"),
    "preferredIndex" : 2,
    "name" : "ground floor"
}
```

> Expected Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187d57396b445745438fe"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "top floor"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4188067396b445745438ff"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "top floor,left top floor"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187657396b445745438fb"),
    "preferredIndex" : 2,
    "name" : "ground floor"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d41878b7396b445745438fc"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "ground floor,bad room"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4187c07396b445745438fd"),
    "preferredIndex" : 1,
    "name" : "ground floor,bad room,bad"
}
```

You can see hear I want to sort document for a parent to child as well as with preferred index. We try some of query but it is not working properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is the expected result sorted according to preferredIndex? The order is 1,1,2,1,1 .

Comment: I want to sort document on two scenarios first parents to the child and preferred index like 
top floor
. . left top floor
ground floor
. . bad room
. . . .bad